# Move to next column after specific number of lines in python

Tags: python, file, row, multiple-columns, lines

If I have a data set that runs:
1
2
3
4
5
6
from a python output, and i want:
1  4
2  5
3  6
basically after a specific number of lines, I would like to move the output into the next column, can this be done in Python?

This is what I currently have:

`aa=[]
    for index, line in enumerate(open("random.txt")):
      if index <= 0: continue
      else:
        holder = line.split("\t")
        dataEle = [ val[6] , val[7] , val[9] , val[10] ]
        dataL.append( dataEle )`

```
for ee in dataL:  
  for line in ee:  
    print line
```

Comment: It certainly can be done in Python. Have you tried doing this yet? Care to share your attempt?

Comment: I am new to using text files in python and thus far have managed only to create the list

Comment: Please explain exactly what you are dealing with. Because it was only in your comment that I realize that you are dealing with a file. Explain your problem as exact as possible. Even though you might have done a little bit of code, show that code and explain exactly what difficulties you are having.

Comment: Please update your question and put that code in there and format it properly using the formatting tools.

Comment: Yes, I did, I realise commenting doesn't facilitate code too well

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = ['1','2','3','4','5','6']

print(lines[:round(len(lines)/2)])

for i in range(round(len(lines)/2)):
    print(lines[i] + lines[i + 3], sep=' ')  
## 1 4 
## 2 5 
## 3 6
```

Anyways you are going to keep your file data in list. So I see that you are able to do it by your own. It is the first idea which came into my mind and I think there are some way to optimize this code. But still I hope you caught the main plot. Good Luck!